# Read Excel file in Oracle database

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, plsql

I want to know a way or procedure or query that can help me to read an excel file. I just want to place the excel file somewhere at my DB server and use a query to display all records of that excel file in a query output. File could be of any length, any number of rows and columns.

I have used as_read_xlsx but it gives data in columns and also separate strings, numbers and dates. I want all data to appear as it is in excel.

Comment: can you make it to csv? as reading csv is quite easy in oracle

Comment: Your case needs an `External` table. Read here how you can create external table. https://techgoeasy.com/oracle-external-tables/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert data directly from Excel to Oracle Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117050/how-to-insert-data-directly-from-excel-to-oracle-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just want to place the excel file somewhere at my DB server and use
>   a query to display all records of that excel file in a query output.
>   File could be of any length, any number of rows and columns.

As mentioned in my comments you would need to create a `External` Table to do so. 
See below:

My `CSV` (Tst.csv) file content:

[image]

Created directory `CSV_FILES` and logged in as `SYS` and granted permission to read & write.

```
GRANT READ,WRITE ON DIRECTORY CSV_FILES TO scott;
```

[image: Directory]

Created `External` table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE TST_TABLE
(
  ACCT_NO                   VARCHAR2(7),
  LOAN_AMOUNT               NUMBER,
  PRODUCT_TYPE              VARCHAR2(3) 
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
  (  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
     DEFAULT DIRECTORY CSV_FILES
     ACCESS PARAMETERS 
       ( RECORDS DELIMITED  BY NEWLINE
         skip 1
         LOGFILE CSV_FILES:'tstlog.log'
         BADFILE CSV_FILES:'tstbad.bad'
         FIELDS TERMINATED BY  ","            
           (
              ACCT_NO            ,
              LOAN_AMOUNT        ,
              PRODUCT_TYPE       
            )
          )
     LOCATION ('Tst.csv'))
     reject limit unlimited;
```

Query the table all records as:

```
SQL> select * from TST_TABLE;

ACCT_NO LOAN_AMOUNT PRO
------- ----------- ---
AFSGSGT       34454 XXX
BSDFFGS       45645 YYY
SFSDFDS       56453 ZZZ
```

Query to select selective records using filter condition:

```
SQL> select * from TST_TABLE where product_type = 'XXX';

ACCT_NO LOAN_AMOUNT PRO
------- ----------- ---
AFSGSGT       34454 XXX
```